# List of lists, lambda and filtering results

Tags: lambda, f#, functional-programming

I want to create two functions:
1) function which finds all elements less than zero in list (int list list) and then return these elements as list of (int list) type.

2) function which finds all numbers that are even on list (float list list) and then returns them as (int list).

Both of them should use at least one lambda expression (fun x -> ... ).

How to create these functions? To be honest I don't know.

```
let findnegative(d:int list list)=
  //maybe    List.map

let findeven (t:float list list) = 
 //something with     List.filter (fun x -> x%2.0 = 0.0)
```

Comment: Use `list |> List.collect id` to transform it from a list of lists to a list. Then apply `List.filter` with your condition.

Comment: @Asti - You can actually use `List.filter ...` instead of `id` as the argument to `List.collect` to do it in a single step.

Comment: what you tried to do to solve the problem?

Comment: @kvb let findeven(t:float list list) = List.map(fun x ->  int(x)) (List.filter (fun x -> x%2.0 = 0.0) t) but it doesn't work ("float doesn't match float list" error)

Comment: not so bad...do you know what does this `|>` operator?

Comment: @matoex : He said to use `List.collect`; that uses `List.map`.

Comment: I know that but using collect I couldn't convert float to int. So how to use List.collect ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
let findnegative(d:int list list) =
  d
  |> List.map (fun x -> x |> List.filter (fun y -> y < 0))
  |> List.collect id

let findeven (t:float list list) = 
  t
  |> List.map (fun x -> x |> List.filter (fun y -> y % 2.0 = 0.0))
  |> List.collect id
  |> List.map int
```

This can be simplified to:

```
let findnegative =
  List.collect <| List.filter ((>)0)

let findeven = 
  List.collect <| List.filter (fun x -> x % 2. = 0.) >> List.map int
```

Comment: it's `x % 2. = 0.` weird for me

Comment: Yeah, I changed it back a few minutes ago. My understanding of the other syntax isn't quite right, I'm investigating.

Comment: Ah, when I was partially applying with `((%)2.)` that was with the `2.` on the wrong side of the operator. Needs the `fun` syntax I believe.

Comment: With the help of a simple help function `flip` it's possible to reduce readability ;): `let findeven = let inline flip f l r = f r l in List.collect <| List.filter (flip (%) 2.0 >> (=) 0.) >> List.map int`

Comment: Haha, nice. Yeah, the longer version is going to be much easier to reason with, the terse version will give you a headache fast.

Comment: `%` for float numbers, I meant it :)

Comment: @Stuart these first solutions are great just because of readability. I think that now I see how it works. I didn't know that `|>` operator and `id` in using `List.collect`. It's also good tip. Thanks guys  : )